# Selenium - locating multiple elements with the same class name

Tags: selenium

Hello there I am trying to locate multiple elements with the same className. The className and the body structure of the elements are the same but the texts, links and pictures are different.

```
  <div class="dc-content-right clearfix"> (parent)
  <div class="dc-item clearfix">        (child nodes) 
  <div class="dc-item clearfix">
  <div class="dc-item clearfix">
```

Each of these child elements looks something like this:

```
<div class="dc-item clearfix">
  <div class="dc-icon">
  <div class="dc-info">
    <h2>
      <a href="http://www.avg.com/ww-en/free-antivirus-download">AVG AntiVirusFree 2015</a>
    </h2>
```

Each child element has **different text** in the H2 tag. So once it is AVG AntiVirus Free 2015, then it is Internet Security .... and so on. So what I want to do is save all elements into a list and then work with them.
At first I save these elements  intto a list of WebElements :

```
List <"WebElement"> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='dc-item clearfix']"));
```

Afterwards I want to iterate through the list and write the h2 text for each element on the screen:

```
for(WebElement i:superDiv)
            {
                System.out.println(i.findElement(By.xpath("//h2/a")).getText());
            }
```

So the outcome should be a list of 3 different headings extracted from `divs`. The **problem**: the outcome is the list of 3 headings which are **the same**!

```
AVG AntiVirus Free 2015
AVG AntiVirus Free 2015
AVG AntiVirus Free 2015
```

It looks like I located the same element 3 times. Does anyone have an idea what could be the problem? Thank you

Answer (score 5):

```
    List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@class='dc-item clearfix']//h2/a"));
    for(WebElement el : list) {
       System.out.println(el.getText());
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, that will write all the text it can found in a child element, (links, descriptions, header...) I would like to access the h2 tag only.

Comment: ya, i misread the question. I have updated the xpath since, does the new one work?

Comment: Yes it does work. Thank you. But the whole point was.. is it possible to first save the whole child element.

List <"WebElement"> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='dc-item clearfix']"));

and then acces the differnt parts of it. Something like 
list.get(1).findElement(By.xpath("//h2/a")).getText().    Do you know wheter something like this is even possible ?

Comment: ah ok, gotcha. I dont know, but i would assume it is possible. trial and error is the only way you'll find out.

Comment: That is also possible. You have to give xpath from child tag of that div element.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try:-

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@class='dc-info']//a"));
    for(WebElement element : list) {
       System.out.println(element.getText());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If div tag does not contains id or class, then use like this

```java
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@style,'height:50px')]"));
for(WebElement element : elements) {
   System.out.println(element.getText());
}
```